# is using IMEI as unique ID and storing it in database against Google play privacy?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-play

I have got an app with sign up page (firebase authentication) and I want to allow user to make only one account per device

**What I've Tried**

using the method below I have tried getting IMEI as unique UID and I stored it in my database so I can check if the user already made an account on my app using their device

```
private String GetDeviceID(){
    TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceID = null;
    int readIMEI= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if(deviceID == null) {
        if (readIMEI == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            deviceID = tm.getDeviceId();
        }
    }
    return deviceID;
}
```

Manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**My question is**

since I'm going to publish my app to Play store
is it against Google play privacy to get user IMEI and store it in database?
I have read their policy but I'm still not sure

or is there any other unique device ID or any method that I can use to achieve this

Comment: `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` requires your app to be installed on the privileged partition or be signed by the platform signing key. "or is there any other unique device ID or any method that I can use to achieve this" -- see [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) for Google's recommendations.

Comment: the if (deviceId == null) check is redundant

Comment: the code isn't my main focus in this question.

Answer (score 0):

use The [Firebase installations service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations) (FIS) which provides a Firebase installation ID (FID) for each installed instance of a Firebase app.

in your app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-installations:17.0.0'
```

to Retrieve client identifiers, in you main activity:

```java
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getId()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("Installations", "Installation ID: " + task.getResult());
        } else {
            Log.e("Installations", "Unable to get Installation ID");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: "Here are some cases where FIDs could be deleted or rotated:

Uninstallation or reinstallation of the app, for instance when an end user installs on a new device.
The end user clears the cache of the app or the device."